# Rails -- submitting a form_for to a non-RESTful method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, form-for

So I know how to submit a form to a server via `form_for` to a model's `create` and `update` methods, but if a model has some method `foobar`, how do I submit a form specifically to the `foobar` method?  I tried specifying `:method => "foobar"` but that didn't seem to do the trick.  How can I submit a `form_for` that goes to a non-RESTful method?

**EDIT:**

I don't want said method to be accessible to anyone by typing the address in their address bar.  eg. `www.site_name.com/controller_name/foobar` should not be valid - the `foobar` method should solely be used for processing the submitted form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:url` [optional parameter](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) to `form_for` to specify the url you want to post to.

```
form_for(@model, :url => foobar_model_path) do |f| 
  ...
end
```

Comment: I should have been more specific in my question - so i want to be able to submit a form_for to a certain method, but I don't want that method / page to actually be accessible by typing it into the address bar - so I want to submit the form to the method foobar but I don't want the user to be able to access said method with www.site_name.com/controller_name/foobar

Comment: Then you need to [specify the route as a post route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) (GET is the method used by browsers just regularly requesting a page).

Comment: I ended up having to specify it with `put` rather than `post` but otherwise that worked thanks